# Is the ColdFusion Event Gateways event queue limit forced on us?

Tags: coldfusion

It looks like the "Maximum number of events to queue" limit must be > 0 (found in CF 8 admin > EVENT GATEWAYS > Settings) and that if this limit is exceeded this some events will be lost..

**I don't want to loose events, so is there some way to set the limit to ∞?**

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the threads queued are GTE the max before adding to the queue

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236261/how-to-know-when-sendgatewaymessage-fails

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to *not* have a limit. However, if you simply don't ever want to lose an event, just set it to an obscenely high number.

Remember, as soon as something is done processing, it's out of the queue and the next item can go in, so set the number much higher than you think your maximum throughput should be, and you're good to go.

Comment: well that might work, except for http://superuser.com/questions/254910/cant-change-coldfusion-8s-event-gateways-settings

Comment: what I really need is a method to determine when a message is lost b/c the event queue is full, so that I can act accordingly..

Comment: Even queue is not the same as threads. You can have one thread (processing one event at a time) and then have multiple events queued and ready to go. As for knowing when something doesn't get queued, I'm not up to speed on that one, as I've never actually hit the limit yet...