# Can't change ColdFusion 8's Event Gateways > Settings

Tags: coldfusion

When I change "Event Gateway Processing Threads" from 1 to anything else, like 10, then press save, the page is refreshed and there is a message that says my settings were saved, but my change is actually lost.. so afaict I cannot change "Event Gateway Processing Threads" to anything but the default, `1`.

How do I change this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of CF are you using? You need to be running Enterprise (not standard or developer) to run more than one concurrent thread on event gateways.

Comment: ah I see that must be it, I'm using the trial on my dev machine, which is prob standard.

Comment: can you link to someplace where I'm supposed to be able to find this information? not that I don't trust you.

Comment: You can see here (http://www.adobe.com/products/coldfusion/editions/) under Advanced Protocol Support, that Enterprise gets the Async gateway while standard does not. The developer edition is actually a somewhat limited Enterprise license. It can do all of the things Enterprise can do, but does have some limitations. I can't seem to find the page that lists those, but a limit on the number of async threads for gateways is one of those limitations...